# Java equivalent of JavaScript's Promise.reject

Tags: java-8, future, completable-future

The title says it all, but what is the Java 8 equivalent of JavaScript's [Promise.reject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)? I'm looking for a static method on [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) that will create a `Future` in an exceptional state, but I don't see one.

Comment: [`CompletableFuture.failedFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#failedFuture(java.lang.Throwable)).

Comment: I think there are many of tutorials about it like https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial/ 
and examples like https://dzone.com/articles/20-examples-of-using-javas-completablefuture 
I'm not really sure what you mean since you already mentioned the equivalent already!

Comment: @BoristheSpider It looks like that feature is only available in Java 10. I should have specified, but I'm looking for the answer in Java 8.

Comment: @Al-Mothafar I have not mentioned the equivalent. I'm *not* looking for an equivalent class, I'm looking for an equivalent method to Promise.reject.

Comment: First, Java 9 - not 10. Second, yes - if you want code for obsolete versions of Java then it is best to specify that in the question.

Comment: That link you posted sent me to the docs for java 10. I see that it's also available in Java 9.

Comment: Indeed. Given that is the current version of Java, it makes sense to reference those documents.

Comment: So do you know the answer in Java 8?